# Kivy with suds - module installation

Tags: python, installation, kivy, suds

I am pretty new to python, my background is with VB visual studios, I am trying to develop a app in which I want to consume WCF service. Found Suds is the required python module.

I am using Kivy 1.8.0 and Eclipse with pydev on Windows 7 64bit.  Could you please point me in correct direction on how to instal the package, found no exe, I have run the setup.py from suds but did not work.

Any advice/direction towards tutorial is of great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you by any chance running the Python 3 version of Kivy? Suds looks like it is abandondonware (last release in 2010) and likely does not have a Python3 port. You may have luck with the Python2.7 version of Kivy and pip installing suds, but keep in mind you will be relying on an apparently unsupported module (suds) for your project.

Comment: Thank you, yes, I am working on Kivy with Python 3.3.

Answer (score 0):

The best tool to install Python modules is `pip`.
With `pip` you don't even need to download installed module because it get it from remote repository.

```
pip search suds 

pip install suds
```

Maybe you have `pip` installed with Python.
Otherwise see page https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip

BTW: Of couser not all modules are available by `pip` but this way you can get most modules.

---

**EDIT:**

Installion `suds` with `pip` looks (on Linux) like this:

```
$ pip install suds

Downloading/unpacking suds
  Downloading suds-0.4.tar.gz (104kB): 104kB downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package suds

Installing collected packages: suds
  Running setup.py install for suds
    /usr/bin/python -O /tmp/tmp5qxEid.py
    removing /tmp/tmp5qxEid.py

Successfully installed suds
Cleaning up...
```

Comment: Tried that from cmd and python interpreter from kivy folder, no luck, receiving invalid syntax.  Still googling, small thing, but making be go back to VB again.